# How To Parse And Extract Nested JSON Response Using SBJson And Objective-C

Tags: ios, json, parsing

Could anyone tell me how to parse and extract just the data node, i.e. CM, Dozen, Foot..., from the JSON response below into an NSMutableArray, so it can be used as data source for UITableView?

`{success: true, dataCount: 11, data:
[{"unitName":"CM"},{"unitName":"Dozen"},{"unitName":"Foot"},{"unitName":"Gross"},{"unitName":"Inch"},{"unitName":"K"},{"unitName":"KG"},{"unitName":"LB"},{"unitName":"Piece"},{"unitName":"Set"},{"unitName":"Yard"}]}`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers

## Update...

### Oli & Srika, You guys are so helpful!

Below is my code...

NSString *myRawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.100/myApp/getUnitInJson.php"]];
//myRawJson response is like below
{success: true, dataCount: 5, data: [{"unitName":"CM"},{"unitName":"Dozen"},{"unitName":"Foot"},{"unitName":"Gross"},{"unitName":"Inch"}]}

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSArray *myParsedJson = [[parser objectWithString:myRawJson error:nil] copy];
NSArray *myExtractedData = [myParsedJson valueForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"RawJsonString: %@", myRawJson);
// ouput: RawJsonString: {data:[{"unitName":"CM"},{"unitName":"Inch"},{"unitName":"Foot"},{"unitName":"Yard"},]}
NSLog(@"myExtractedData Count: %@", [myExtractedData count]);
// output: myExtractedData Count: (null)

There is nothing in myExtractedData. Am I doing anything wrong?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

to get `data` from the entire `NSDictionary` -
 `NSArray values = [data objectForKey:@"data"]`. 
This give the `NSArray` associated with `data`.

to get CM try this -`NSString *CM = [[values objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"unitName"]`
The same goes for Dozen, Foot. etc.

You can then put this data in `UITableView`.

**UPDATE:** Try this. I am assuming you are using [**this**](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) as JSON parser.

```
NSDictionary *myParsedJson = [myRawJson JSONValue];
NSArray *myExtractedData = [myParsedJson valueForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"myExtractedData Count: %@", [myExtractedData count]);
```

Comment: Srikar, thank you very much for your quick reply. But is there a getObjectForKey method for NSMutableArray? I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: sorry, typo!!. it should be `objectForKey` is for `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Srikar, I just updated my question. Please have a look at it and help me out.

Comment: @Wong, isn't this `NSArray *myParsedJson` wrong? should it not be `NSDictionary`?

Comment: I just change it to NSDictionary *myParsedJson, but the result is the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the SBJson framework. NSDictionary *myParsedJson = [myRawJson JSONValue]; results in a runtime error -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object key string expected\" UserInfo=0x4b545a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Object key string expected}"

Comment: my json response is {success: true, dataCount: 11, data: [{"unitName":"CM"},{"unitName":"Dozen"},{"unitName":"Foot"},{"unitName":"Gross"},{"unitName":"Inch"},{"unitName":"K"},{"unitName":"KG"},{"unitName":"LB"},{"unitName":"Piece"},{"unitName":"Set"},{"unitName":"Yard"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Are you letting the user add/modify the array in the UITableView, is that why you need it to be mutable?

In any case, here's how you can do it: access the data array from the "wholeResponse" dictionary, then turn that array into a mutable one.

```
NSArray *data = [wholeResponse valueForKey:@"data"];
NSMutableArray *mutableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:data];

// Do something with the mutable data.
```

Comment: Hi Oli, Thank you for your quick reply. I just updated my question. Please check it out and help me out.